# How do I remove a some properties from an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, arraylist, angular2-services

Say I create an object as follows:

```
formSummery: any = [];

{
  "jobs" : [ {
    "job_id" : 10,
    "users" : [ {
      "user_id" : 11,
      "data_points" : [ {
        "efficiency" : "good",
        "form_id" : "2",
        "instrument_type" : "plug",
        "background_value" : "7",
        "surveyed_item_id" : "100",
        "duration" : 0,
        "start_time" : "2017-07-20T04:04:43.000Z",
        "datastream" : "GENERIC",
        "username" : "abc@gmail.com.com"
      }]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

What is the best way to remove the property datastream, username and start_time to end up with new formSummery as follows?

```
{
  "jobs" : [ {
    "job_id" : 10,
    "users" : [ {
      "user_id" : 11,
      "data_points" : [ {
        "efficiency" : "good",
        "form_id" : "2",
        "instrument_type" : "plug",
        "background_value" : "7",
        "surveyed_item_id" : "100",
        "duration" : 0
      }]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Now, I have two same arrays formSummery and unstrdformSummery , and I want to delete some properties from second array (unstrdformSummery) and those properties still want in first array (formSummery):

```
formSummery = 
{ 
    "planned_activity":"Yes",
    "ingest_time":"2017-08-03T12:12:32.456Z",
    "arrival_time":"8",
    "device_id":"26e09c88237d5342",
    "user_name":"ABC","form_id":"1",
    "firmware_version":"2.2",
    "site_access_was_provided_as_expected":"Yes",
    "energy_manager":"Aaaa",
    "duration":0,
    "start_time":"2017-08-03T12:12:28.736Z",
    "datastream":"GENERIC",
    "addressing_percent_complete":"92",
    "password":"pwd",
    "template_name":"Daily Field Report",
    "user_id":11,
    "site_access_notes":"testing",
    "startup_percent_complete":"65",
    "energy_manager_ip":"0:0:0:0",
    "was_site_access_granted_on_time":"Yes",
    "departure_time":"9",
    "username":"abc@gmail.com"
}


unstrdformSummery =
{
    "planned_activity":"Yes",
    "ingest_time":"2017-08-03T12:12:32.456Z",
    "arrival_time":"8",
    "device_id":"26e09c88237d5342",
    "user_name":"ABC","form_id":"1",
    "firmware_version":"2.2",
    "site_access_was_provided_as_expected":"Yes",
    "energy_manager":"Aaaa",
    "duration":0,
    "start_time":"2017-08-03T12:12:28.736Z",
    "datastream":"GENERIC",
    "addressing_percent_complete":"92",
    "password":"pwd",
    "template_name":"Daily Field Report",
    "user_id":11,
    "site_access_notes":"testing",
    "startup_percent_complete":"65",
    "energy_manager_ip":"0:0:0:0",
    "was_site_access_granted_on_time":"Yes",
    "departure_time":"9",
    "username":"abc@gmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, you can do it by calling simple `delete` function:

```
var myObject = {
    "jobs": [{
        "job_id": 10,
        "users": [{
            "user_id": 11,
            "data_points": [{
                "efficiency": "good",
                "form_id": "2",
                "instrument_type": "plug",
                "background_value": "7",
                "surveyed_item_id": "100",
                "duration": 0,
                "start_time": "2017-07-20T04:04:43.000Z",
                "datastream": "GENERIC",
                "username": "abc@gmail.com.com"
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

for (let i = 0; i < myObject.jobs.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < myObject.jobs[i].users.length; j++){
        for (let g = 0; g < myObject.jobs[i].users[j].data_points.length; g++){
            delete myObject.jobs[i].users[j].data_points[g].username;
            delete myObject.jobs[i].users[j].data_points[g].datastream;
            delete myObject.jobs[i].users[j].data_points[g].start_time;
        }
    }
}
```

If it will be also 1 user only , and 1 job, 1 data_points, you can use sth like that:

```
delete myObject.jobs[0].users[0].data_points[0].username;
delete myObject.jobs[0].users[0].data_points[0].datastream;
delete myObject.jobs[0].users[0].data_points[0].start_time;
```

------EDIT

If you want to store old object with all parameters, you can clone your object before deleting. You can use [Object.clone](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/clone/) function or just simple use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` (i used it in example). You can't use simple `var newObj = object` (if you will change object, newobj will be also changed)

```
formSummery = 
{ 
    "planned_activity":"Yes",
    "ingest_time":"2017-08-03T12:12:32.456Z",
    "arrival_time":"8",
    "device_id":"26e09c88237d5342",
    "user_name":"ABC","form_id":"1",
    "firmware_version":"2.2",
    "site_access_was_provided_as_expected":"Yes",
    "energy_manager":"Aaaa",
    "duration":0,
    "start_time":"2017-08-03T12:12:28.736Z",
    "datastream":"GENERIC",
    "addressing_percent_complete":"92",
    "password":"pwd",
    "template_name":"Daily Field Report",
    "user_id":11,
    "site_access_notes":"testing",
    "startup_percent_complete":"65",
    "energy_manager_ip":"0:0:0:0",
    "was_site_access_granted_on_time":"Yes",
    "departure_time":"9",
    "username":"abc@gmail.com"
}

newForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formSummery));


delete newForm.username;
delete newForm.datastream;
delete newForm.start_time;
```

newForm object will be store new object without theses parameteres, and formSummery will store old object (all parameters).

I hope it helps.

Comment: but the problem is delete properties from all objects.

Comment: I have two different objects for same properties and I want to delete some properties only from one object.

Comment: You can use index instead of foreach as i show in the example.

Comment: Can you include your actual code (objects) to your post?

Comment: I don't see that you changed anything. Just edit your post and include new formatted code on the bottom.